# Using aggregate function on a column of type character varying

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to execute the following **hql query**.

```
String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT SUM(quantity) as sum FROM SalesDetails sd";
Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();)
{
    int row =  Integer.parseInt((String) it.next());
    System.out.print("MAX QUANTITY: " + row);
}
```

The data type of 'quantity' used in the model class is **String**. But when I try to execute the query, it gives an error.

```
ERROR: ERROR: function sum(character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 8
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Please help. How will I execute the SUM function on a String value in hibernate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are using native sql functions in HQL query. either change query type to NativeSqlQuery or use hibernate criterion .

Comment: sum can be applied on numbers, floats, not on strings.. what is quanity field supposed to hold and mapped to what kind of column in db ?

Comment: Change your data field `quantity` to a numeric type!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do a SUM on characters if you are sure that quantity will always be a number the cast it to a number before doing a SUM

so

```
"SELECT SUM(to_number(quantity)) as sum FROM SalesDetails sd";
```

will convert the character to number and then pass it to the SUM function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select sum(cast(quantity as integer)) as sum FROM SalesDetails sd";
```

Before sum function just cast it to integer.